# Google maps plugin appears as grey box (MVC environment)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I am trying to, as per stated in title, implement a google maps plugin into the site I am working on, but with little success:

the map loads - however, it remains grey. All other controls on the map seems to be working (clicking the logo opens google maps at the right lat/lng + zoom location, terms of service button working etc.)

any Ideas what I am missing in my implementation?

Html:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="auctionMap">
     <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Lat" id="lat" />
     <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Long" id="lng" />
     <div id="basic_map" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>         
</div>
```

JS :

```
<script>
    function initMap() {


      var uluru = {
        lat: parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat').value),
        lng: parseFloat(document.getElementById('lng').value),
      }

        google.maps.visualRefresh = true; 
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat').value), parseFloat(document.getElementById('lng').value));
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('basic_map'), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map
        });

    }
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SECRETKEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

** edit **

Discovery: running `initMap` after the page finished loading with the map VISIBLE on the screen loads the map correctly. if the map is not visible (i.e another tab is selected - this map is particularly on a bootstrap `.tab-control` - it remains gray

Comment: Would you mind posting the corrected code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this for your script.

```
           <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAPKeBYFqGsbfGiH7wvx1mMH9A4I" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: You're missing the point: I am doing an asynchronous and deferred load of the script so it doesn't block up the page load. the callback is supposed to call initMap() after it's done. it does that at least...

Comment: <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps APIs require a key.

You can get one from here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: I do have a key. I removed it in my sample above.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, I did not post the code that the google map is on a bootstrap tab-panel. It is initially invisible / not rendered to the screen, and my edit gave the clue away:

> Discovery: running initMap after the page finished loading with the
>   map VISIBLE on the screen loads the map correctly. if the map is not
>   visible (i.e another tab is selected - this map is particularly on a
>   bootstrap .tab-control - it remains gray

Simply attaching a click listener to the tab where the map was on and recalling `initMap()` displayed the map again because this time, the `div` in which the map is loaded is visible again, and it has something to render to. I deserve my downvotes here.